# Using generics and a singly linked list (error CS0311)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, singly-linked-list

I have a task to create a collection using a singly linked list and generics. To create a singly linked list I made a special class, nothing unusual.

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public Node(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
}
```

Then I made a short interface where I've wrote all necessary things to work with list. There is some fragment to show:

```
interface ICustomCollection<T>
{
    void Add(T item);
}
```

And then I used this interface in a new class of collection:

```
class MyCustomCollection<T> : ICustomCollection<T> where T: Node<T>
{
    T head;
    T tail;
    T current;
    int count = 0;

    public void Add (T item)
    {
        Node<T> node = new(null);

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = (T)node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.Next = node;
        }
        tail = (T)node;

        count++;
        current = tail;
    }
}
```

Let it be all the functional of the collection. So then I create new class called Person with name:

```
public class Person
{
    string name;
}
```

So I need to create a class instance to use the collection:

```
MyCustomCollection<Person> people;
```

But now I have a compiler error CS0311 saying that there is no implicit reference conversion from "Person" to 'Node'. I can't really understand what to do with that, I even tried to do something like:

```
public static explicit operator Node<Person>(Person person)
{
    return new Node<Person>(person.name){ Next = null, Name = person.name };
}
```

but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: I don't understand why you need `MyCustomCollection` in the first place? Your `Node<T>` class is already all you need for a singly linked list.

Comment: Your custom collection requires that it be parameterised by a type *that derives from `Node<T>` itself*. That seems an unusual requirement for the collection class to impose. Why did you add that `where`?

Comment: Your `Node<T>` class has nothing generic in it. You have a string and you have a reference to next node. You don't have any generic data member in it. You can simply have a `Node` class without any generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to require that the collection can only contain things that themselves derive from `Node<T>`. So don't impose that as a requirement. Just use `Node<T>` internally:

```
class MyCustomCollection<T> : ICustomCollection<T>
{
    Node<T> head;
    Node<T> tail;
    Node<T> current;
    int count = 0;
```

At that point, you might also consider moving the `Node` class inside your collection class and making it private (if you do that, you'd no longer need to parameterise `Node` itself since it could use the enclosing `T` parameter of the collection)

You probably also need to make your `Node<T>` be *capable of storing a `T`* as a property.

Comment: @NavjotSingh - because once they've stopped confusing the Nodes for the items contained in the collections, the Node ought to have a property of type `T` to store the item.

Comment: Yes totally agreed

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yea, I think you are right, and I thought about that too, but according to the task I need to use T on methods (e.x. "T Current()", which shows current element, but using your solution I need to write "Node<T> Current()". And it works, but I thought about how to leave that T, not Note<T>. But I guess that's not that important, so thanks, you proved that I have right ideas about that.

Comment: @ГлебБуткевич You don't need to do `Node<T> Current()`, you can still do `T Current()`. The point of this answer is to suggest that you should make `Node<T>` an _invisible implementation detail` of your linked list structure. In other words, calling code doesn't need to know about `Node<T>`, it is only used internally.